# Word for "someone who talks too much"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms, pejorative-language

What is another word for a person who likes to talk too much. I was thinking *bigmouth*, but *bigmouth* could mean "somebody who likes carrying messages voluntarily".

Comment: *Garrulous* is the word that comes to mind. http://www.google.com/#q=garrulous

Comment: [Big mouth](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/big-mouth?q=big+mouth) does not mean "somebody who likes carrying messages voluntarily".

Answer (score 5):

The word is *chatterbox*, but it's rather informal. The second part of your question is not about English, but the answer is probably 'No'.

Answer (score 2):

Someone who talks too much can be referred to as:

- blabbermouth
- squealer
- windbag

Answer (score 2):

Other words for this are

**gasbag** http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/gasbag?q=gasbag

**loudmouth** http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/loudmouth?topic=speakers-and-talkers

**motormouth** http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/motormouth?topic=speakers-and-talkers

**talker** http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/talker?topic=speakers-and-talkers

Answer (score 1):

If you need an excuse to end the flow of words and pay someone a compliment at the same time, I offer this suggestion. There's no guarantee the talker won't be offended, but if said in the right tone of voice and with charm, you might get away with it.

> "I could listen to you for hours on end, it's such a pleasure to meet
>   someone who is so
>   [**loquacious**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/loquacious)
>   but unfortunately, I have an urgent appointment/meeting which I have to go to."

If however; you only need to interrupt this person, try saying:

- "Could I just interrupt you and say... "
- "If I could just stop you there and add... "
- "I absolutely agree with everything you said so far and I'd like to mention... "

Comment: I was looking at this answer, and I thought to myself "How weird. It's totally off-topic" And then I looked back at the OP's edits. In the *original* version, the questioner specifically asks: "Is their (sic) a way to stop / pause somebody from talking without hurting sentiments".

Answer (score 1):

***Blatherskate***

***Gascon*** if you are not in France.

***Popinjay*** if you are not in Spain