# What would you call a person who shares every thought they have?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

What would you call a person who thinks they know everything and decides to share every little fact they can think of? For example, if a teacher or professor says something and a student decides to say "oh, interusting fact about this" or "one time, something happened relevant to something you just mentioned", but then they go off topic and say non relevant stories and the whole classroom falls asleep. Or is there not a word for this?

Comment: "Diarrhea of the mouth" is a common (if inelegant) expression that is often used.

Comment: @Hot Licks: That's the AmE version - in BrE it's invariably [*verbal diarrhea*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=verbal+diarrhea%2Cdiarrhea+of+the+mouth&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cverbal%20diarrhea%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: "Blogger" is another term that comes to mind.

Comment: @FumbleFingers One thing I would expect of anyone who had won first prize in life's lottery would be that they could spell *diarrhoea*.

Comment: @WS2: I just cut & pasted from HotLicks and Bib's text for my NGram link above (but if I'm honest, I didn't notice, 'cos my spelling is "flakey" at best! :). On the other hand it's interesting to compare it with [the NGram with the "correct" spelling](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=verbal+diarrhoea%2Cdiarrhoea+of+the+mouth&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cverbal%20diarrhoea%3B%2Cc0). In my first NGram, *diarrhea of the mouth* is the preferred AmE version. In the second, *diarrhoea of the mouth* simply doesn't exist!

Comment: Modern teenagers on Twitter

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps because we call it *verbal diarrhoea*. You know, *mental constipation* and *verbal diarrhoea*.

Comment: I second and third the  "verbal diarrhea" response.

Comment: @HotLicks or "Tweeter"

Comment: @WS2: The point of my *first* comment was to show that "verbal xxxxx" is the more common form - which is in fact true both sides of the pond, with the standard spelling. But curiously (to me, at least) Hot Licks's *non-standard spelling* version is actually more common that the "correctly" spelled version in the [Google Books AmE corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=diarrhea+of+the+mouth%2Cdiarrhoea+of+the+mouth&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdiarrhea%20of%20the%20mouth%3B%2Cc0) ("xxxxx of the mouth" is too rare to graph in BrE).

Comment: There is also the relatively recent term "over-sharer", though my observation has been that it's usually limited to use by women describing other women who spill far too many details of their private lives.

Comment: Related: [Is there a word for a person who gives out too many extraneous details?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/15940/26083) and [Word for “someone who talks too much”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/130094/26083).

Comment: @HotLicks logorrhea.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "Diarrhea" is one of those US/UK things.  It's very rare to see it spelled with the "o" in the US.

Comment: (And my spell checker on Firefox accepts only the US spelling.)

Answer (score 7):

The person can be said to suffer from *[verbal diarrhea](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/verbal-diarrhea)*

> The fact or habit of talking too much:
>   *was it necessary to have the narrator exhibit verbal diarrhea throughout the entire picture?* [*Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

Similarly *[logorrhea](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/logorrhea)*

> excessive, uncontrollable, or incoherent talkativeness [*Collins*]

And, by extension, they might be called a *[logorrheic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/logorrhea#logorrhea)*.

More simply, they might be called a *blatherer*. *Oxford* defines *[blather](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/blather)* as

> Talk long-windedly without making very much sense:
>   *she began blathering on about spirituality and life after death*

Comment: Yes, blather is what a prattler says.

Answer (score 7):

Prattler is the word that comes to mind.

Comment: *Prattle* just refers to foolish, idle talk, not compulsive logorrhea.

Comment: Not sure about that. I think 'prattler' is precisely the right word.

Comment: Obviously you do. It's your answer, after all.

Comment: I believe, just from anecdotal observation, that this may be a US/UK-Commonwealth difference. It's almost exclusively used to describe children, or childish/child-like patterns of speech in the places I've lived Stateside... and in the US literature I've come across. British commedians and writers seem to use it in a much broader sense. And much more commonly. Like I say, this is purely anecdotal. But I skew very heavily towards American literature, and British television in my media consumption patterns... so I'm 80% sure there's something there.

Answer (score 5):

I might call them a "[chatterbox](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chatterbox)".

> An extremely talkative person.

The [definition on Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Chatterbox) might not be as academic, but it certainly matches your description.

> Someone who never shuts the hell up. They keep blabbering about random crap that makes no sense

Answer (score 4):

If the person usually ends up off topic, and you want to express that point, I'd consider using [***digressive***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/digressive) (although it seems to be more commonly used to describe conversations/text rather than people); as Collins has it:

> digressing or given to digression

As Hellion notes below, *serial digressor*, or perhaps just *digressor*, would work if you're looking for a noun instead of an adjective.

Otherwise, [***garrulous***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/garrulous) might be a better fit.

> talking much or too much, esp. about unimportant things; loquacious

Comment: They could even be *serial digressors*...

Answer (score 4):

Hard to think of a good noun option. Blabbermouth. Motormouth. Windbag. They all sound somewhat dated. Although I do like windbag.

Adjectives that might help: "prattling," "filterless," and "windy."

Or you could get metaphorical. In college, who we nicknamed a kid who did that "Filibuster" -- it stuck.

Comment: On the lines of windbag is gaspot. Both are colourful expressions but they are used in reference to someone who talks tall and is usually unable to walk it. A boaster or a dissembler, basically.

Answer (score 3):

It's an informal neologism, but *oversharer* is an increasingly commonly used descriptor, as a quick google search will show.

Comment: I wouldn't use *oversharer* myself for this scenario. To me, an *oversharer* over-shares *personal* information, either in excessive quantity or in contravention of social norms about matters that should be kept private and offline. Oversharers tweet every meal they consume, or post photos from their sexual encounters on Facebook. Someone who tirelessly interjects trivial facts I would call a [Brainy Smurf](http://smurfs.wikia.com/wiki/Brainy_Smurf), though that's probably just showing my age.

Answer (score 1):

I like ***verbally incontinent***, as Mark Darcy described Bridget Jones.

Answer (score 0):

Answers you have so far address the constant talkativeness, but there is one aspect related to your question which has not been addressed, and that's the concept that the talkativeness is triggered by always having a story or embellishment to other people's situations/dialogue. This is known as 'one-upmanship' [(Mirriam Websters definition)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one-upmanship).

One-upmanship is a competitive desire to always have something to add that is just that next step better than what other people have, say, or do. People who try to one-up others often interject with a 'better' story, or a 'more interesting' fact.

Sort of like this answer, actually.

Answer (score 0):

extrovert processor is the technical term, Cognitive thoughts are processed externally with verbalization, as opposed to internally.

Answer (score 0):

If the intention of one persons continuous, unending - and not unusually - monotone speech was to to hog the conversation, and not notice or recognise the drooping eyelids and possibly tunnel like yawns of others in the vicinity - maybe even a collections of zzzZZZs too, then the title 'smart arse' or 'creep' may be applied.

If his boss is present then another term should be applied...... But he'd probably be too pompous, uncaring and stupid to realise.

Does that remind you of someone you've ever had to work with?!

Answer (score -2):

Such a person could be called, unimaginatively, a *know-it-all*. Some might consider it a bit childish these days, but its use is quite common among all ages (at least in American English).

Comment: Anyone care to explain why they think this is a bad answer?

Answer (score -3):

I would describe them as opinionated maybe?

Comment: opinionated means: "conceitedly assertive and dogmatic in one's opinions.", does not necessarily indicate someone who shares every thought.

Comment: Welcome to E&U. You may wish to review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help); a good answer provides an explanation, including suitable references.